# Okta Spring - How to deliberately override 401 and redirect to 404

Tags: spring-security, okta

I have set up a basic okta spring app. Instead of getting a 401 and being redirected to the sign-in page when I hit an endpoint without being logged in, I would like to throw a 404.

Is this possible with Okta or extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter? It seems like it's deadset on 401 instead of 404, and I cannot find any documentation.

My present WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter looks as follows. I was hoping a ControllerAdvice plus Exception handler would do the trick.

```java
@Configuration
    static class CustomSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.authorizeRequests()
                    // allow anonymous access to the home page
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    // all other requests are locked down
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();

            // Send a 401 message to the browser (w/o this, you'll see a redirect to sign-in page)
            Okta.configureResourceServer401ResponseBody(http);
        }

    }
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.okta.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>okta-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please share your security configuration and dependencies.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana , updated. Only dependency is this. Very minimal implementation.

Comment: You can customize the `authenticationEntryPoint` on `oauth2ResourceServer`, however be aware that the default implementation follows [RFC6750](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750).